# Отменённая автором ответа правка

Tags: обсуждение

Нужно ли мне что-то делать, если автор ответа отменил правку, после того, как её приняли?
Вредна ли моя правка?

[Версии поста.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/753252/revisions)

Comment: Сам вопрос, на который дан ответ, несомненно, ужасен. Хотя бы потому, что ответ на него гуглится моментально, со всеми необходимыми уточнениями:)

Comment: из того что ответ гуглится не следует, что вопрос плохой

Comment: Если вы хотите что-то уточнить в ответе - используйте комментарии. Не стоит править код в чужих ответах, не стоит исправлять технические проблемы, и не стоит дописывать текст, чтобы "сделать ответ понятнее". Т.к. "понятнее" - субъективная оценка.

Comment: @PashaPash т.е., в случае с контентом, который я добавил, мне стоило просто дать новый ответ?

Comment: @svgrafov да (15 символов)

Comment: @PashaPash, напиши ответ что ли