# Вопросы помечаются связанными даже если ответ со ссылкой удалён

Tags: дефект, удаление-ответов

Вопрос 1: [Отменённая автором ответа правка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6510/178988)
Вопрос 2: [Тревога - "не по теме" - можно ли просить посоветовать ПО/библиотеку и т. п.?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6511/178988)

Эти вопросы связаны ссылкой в удалённом ответе.
Полагаю, такая связь не должна создаваться и сохраняться?

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: Не вижу тут чего-то криминального. Не нужна связь - можно просто удалить ссылку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если с 2011 года в этой части ничего не изменилось, то такое поведение является "by design": [Posts linked in deleted answers still show up under "Linked"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64743/339911)

Ссылки обновляются каждые 30 дней.

Comment: Тут есть нюанс: насколько я помню, ответ уже был удалён на момент появления в нём ссылки, правда, действовал grace-период.

Comment: ну что там, месяц не прошёл ещё?

Comment: @Qwertiy пора писать на MSE