# Две недели с удаления более не нужных комментариев с заданными словами без проверки модераторами

Tags: обсуждение, тревоги, комментарии

Две недели назад [мы добавили](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7095/) на сайт возможность удалить комментарий по тревоге «более не является необходимым» без проверки модераторами, если комментарий содержит заданные слова. Мы задали следующие слова: вопрос, ответ, спасибо, код, комментарий. С момента старта инициативы сообщество удалило 51 комментарий (в том числе с проверкой модераторами). 13 из них содержат слово «спасибо», 3 слово «вопрос»,7 «ответ», 3 «комментарий».

Я выгрузил *все удаленные по тревоге комментарии* и разместил их по ссылке: http://assets.rudevs.ru/no_longer_needed/19_04_2018.csv

Подчеркну, по ссылке *все удаленные комментарии по тревоге*, как с проверкой модераторами, так и без. Таким образом, комментарии, которые не содержат слов «спасибо», «код», «вопрос», «ответ», «комментарий» удалены вручную после проверки модераторами, те, что содержат — автоматически.

Пожалуйста, просмотрите на удаленные комментарии. Если у вас есть какие–либо замечания, пожалуйста, напишите об этом, чтобы мы вместе могли улучшить процессы и алгоритм удаления более не нужных комментариев, которые не добавляют новых знаний на сайт.

---

На мой взгляд, все удаления по делу. Опасения про «супер чистку» всего и вся не подтвердилось. Пожалуйста, дайте знать, если у вас сложилось другое впечатление!

**Обновление**

Добавил два раздельных файла: первый с удаленными комментариями по тревоге после проверки модераторами, второй — автоматикой, без ручной проверки человеком. Теперь файл содержит идентификатор родительского сообщения (вопроса или ответа) и текст самого комментария, можно посмотреть «контекст».

1. Комментарии, удаленные после ручной проверки модераторами: http://assets.rudevs.ru/no_longer_needed/23_04_2018_by_mods.csv
2. Комментарии, удаленные автоматикой: http://assets.rudevs.ru/no_longer_needed/23_04_2018_by_regexp.csv

Пожалуйста, если у вас есть замечания, расскажите о них!

Comment: Всего 51 комментарий? Пока выборка очень мала, нужно накопить, хотя бы тысячу, думаю.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Да, полностью согласен. Вопрос был в том, найдутся ли те, кто будет вредительствовать и на сколько большим может быть урон. Пока его нет. Будем двигаться дальше и наблюдать.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, да уже по этим всё видно.

Comment: Без контекста непонятно вообще ничего, ситуация может быть как прекрасной, так и ужасной

Comment: @andreymal, вот именно.

Comment: @andreymal В следующем отчете добавлю ссылку на родительское сообщение. В любом случае, мне не ясно, зачем контекст к большинству комментариям вида «спасибо, помогло». Из их содержимого видно, что они не добавляют никакой новой информации ни к вопросу, ни к ответу. Подскажите, что мне следует добавить в следующий отчет, кроме идентификатора родительского сообщения?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky по «спасибо, помогло» никаких проблем, Qwertiy в своём ответе выписал проблемные примеры, которым нужен контекст

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky контекст иногда требует видеть и текст вопроса тоже, например «да, забыл указать что она конструктор» или «Стоит windows 10» можно удалять, если информация была дописана в текст вопроса, а если не была, то их удаление это уже вандализм какой-то. Получить доступ к тексту вопроса по данным из csv у меня как-то не получилось

Comment: @andreymal В данном отчете нет идентификатора родительского сообщения, извиняюсь. «Стоит windows 10» и аналогичные комментарии, которые не содержат слов «спасибо», «код», «вопрос», «ответ», «комментарий» удалены вручную после проверки модераторами.

Comment: Это все хорошо, но допустим есть комментарий аля "Спасибо, но данное решение не подходит, т.к. ...(разъяснение ситуации)", почему данный комментарий должен быть удален? Разве он не несет смысловой нагрузки на ответ?

Answer (score 13):

Смотрю на комментарии - без контекста совершенно невозможно понять, надо было удалять б**о**льшую их часть или нет.

---

> Спасибо, Ваш ответ помог мне.
>
> Огромное спасибо, работает как надо!

Как всегда - [пообсуждали](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7102/178988), вопрос прибили и всё сделали наооборот.

> спасибо, а 6 плоскостей получается на пирамиде это ее 6 граней(сторон)?

А тут вообще "спасибо" просто так написано - вот сразу ложное срабатывание.

> Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как переименовать файлы через cmd?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/815046/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-cmd)

А вот это вообще шедевр - ссылки на дубликаты можем удалять по первой тревоге.
Комментарии про дубликаты обычно полезны, даже если дубликат не подтверился.

---

> Функция `foo` является конструктором? Других вариантов просто не вижу.
> да, забыл указать что она конструктор
>
> @АндрейNOP да, выдаёт ошибку "Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "System.Uri" в "System.Windows.Media.ImageSource"."
>
> "выдаёт ошибку при её вызове" - какую ошибку?
>
> Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x77BA6F38 (ntdll.dll) в Ito1.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00790720.
>
> Если для этого исключения имеется обработчик, выполнение программы может быть продолжено безопасно.
>
> @Grundy одиннадцать с чем-то тысяч
>
> @MadFox поменяйте заодно строчку `sum+=avgsumm[index];`, чтобы не было "+", а то я что-то не пойму, для чего он
>
> Версия операционной системы?
> Стоит windows 10
>
> Причем тут литература?

Сами комментарии (эти, да и многие другие) никак не говорят о своей актуальности - нужен контекст. <s>Кстати, по сути это тоже ложные срабатывания, потому что самого комментария абсолютно недостаточно, чтобы сказать, была ли информация из него перенесена в само сообщение.</s> Говорят, это удалено вручную.

Comment: `@АндрейNOP да, выдаёт ошибку "Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "System.Uri" в "System.Windows.Media.ImageSource"."` это удалялось модератором вручную, ибо под шаблон не попадает, я лично ставил тревогу как неактуальный комментарий. Подозреваю, что большая часть остальных - тоже

Comment: *Как всегда - пообсуждали* — обсуждения не было, это было голосование. Голосования не добавляют какую–либо полезную информацию о проблеме. В принятии решений мы никогда не будем на них опираться. *а 6 плоскостей получается* — удалено автором ответа, после того, как он дополнил ответ! _Возможный дубликат вопроса_ — возможно, это действительно место, где следует обратить внимание. Правда, сам комментарий добавлен системой, при голосе за закрытие. Хоть комментарий и удален, но голос остался, и если попробовать проголосовать за закрытие дубликатом, вопрос–дубль будет отображаться корректно.

Comment: Подскажите, почему (и какой) нужен контекст к комментарию «Спасибо,сейчас проверю»? Что именно вызывает сомнения? Комментарий не запрашивает новую информацию, он не дополняет ответ или вопрос. После того, как его прочитает автор ответа, он теряет любую смысловую нагрузку!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky 1. Ну так надо было в список включать не всё подряд - что ты показал, то я и прокомментировал. 2. Про голосования не согласен. 3. Кем добавлен - не важно, но если как дубликат не закроют как дубликат, то ссылка на связанный вопрос полезна - не случайно же система удаляет такой комментарий именно после закрытия. 4. Никакие _"сейчас проверю"_ я не цитировал.

Comment: Ссылки на связанные вопросы все равно в блоке справа остаются даже после удаления комментариев. Другой вопрос - кто их смотрит...

Comment: @АндрейNOP, нет, исчезают, но не сразу. Я где-то тут на эту тему вопрос задавал.

Comment: Приведенные вами комментарии в последнем блоке — это не ложные срабатывания и не могут ими быть, так как тревоги для этих комментариев обрабатывались вручную модераторами.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, так зачем ты их в файл включил? Как я должен узнать, что кем обрабатывалось?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, вот про 30 дней говорят: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6515/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy Не раз писал, что комментарии, которые не содержат слов «спасибо», «код», «вопрос», «ответ», «комментарий» удалены вручную после проверки модераторами.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, ну так может выложишь файл без них?

Comment: Нет. Важно понимать всю картину, а не только ее часть. Регулярное выражение, по которому идет удаление — [известно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7095/). Имея все данные, любом может оценить какие комментарии удалены «автоматикой», какие после проверки «человеком» и сравнить результаты.

Comment: @PashaPash Массовая чистка — не была целью. Цель — разгрузить модераторов от ручной проверки того, что можно проверить автоматически.

Comment: я понимаю эмоции, но не вижу пользы от языка типа "как всегда пообсуждали ... и сделали наоборот" употреблять: это неконструктивно  и неверно буквально (не соответствует действительности — по указанной ссылки нет консенсуса)¶ Пока рано какие-либо выводы делать на основе 50 комментариев, а про недостатки с конкретными regex уже было сказано. Желательно конечно, чтобы без модераторов гораздо уже класс комментариев по одной тревоге удалялся бы. Но в целом правильный подход: следует автоматизировать вещи, где думать не надо (повторяющиеся действия, если они частые). https://xkcd.com/1205/

Comment: ещё https://xkcd.com/1319/