# Удаленные комментарии по тревоге «более не является необходимым» с 24.04.2018 по 10.07.2018

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, комментарии, тревоги

Представляю вашему вниманию удаленные комментарии по тревоге «более не является необходимым» за период с 24.04.2018 по 10.07.2018. [Как и ранее](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7155/6), комментарии разбиты на два файла (типа):

1. Комментарии, удаленные после ручной проверки модераторами: http://assets.rudevs.ru/no_longer_needed/07-10-2018_by_mods.csv
2. Комментарии, удаленные автоматикой: http://assets.rudevs.ru/no_longer_needed/07-10-2018_by_regexp.csv

Сама инициатива раскрыта в вопросе [Автоматическое удаление комментариев по тревоге «более не является необходимым»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7095/6).

Если вы видите какие–либо недочеты, пожалуйста, дайте знать! Если по-вашему мнению следует несколько изменить формат публикуемого файла с данными, пожалуйста, обязательно напишите, какие поля необходимо добавить, упомянув зачем / почему они нужны / важны.

Comment: Похоже, автокомментарии "Возможный дубликат..." сейчас удаляются автоматически по тревоге, даже пока вопрос еще на проверке в очереди закрытия. Я думаю, должны удаляться только после завершения проверки в очереди.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Да, совершенно верно. Предполагается, что данный комментарий будет удаляться в уже рассмотренных вопросах. Подчеркну, что удаление происходит не в полностью автоматическом режиме — один из участников отмечает его тревогой и лишь после этого идет обработка комментария.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/837768/Как-сделать-сортировку-по-ФИО - в этом вопросе мой автокомментарий исчез до того, как вопрос закрыли.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Спасибо! Вижу по комментариям, что участник удалил ваш комментарий, так как по его мнению можно предложить более точный дубликат (это написано в комментарии ниже, который был удален самим автором некоторое время спустя). Большое спасибо за пример!

Comment: по какому правилу 851633 комментарий удалили? (задан был обширный вопрос, поэтому посыл в гугл оправдан и **приведена явная ссылка** нс ответом на возможно более узкую интерпретацию вопроса—комментарий информативный).¶ В сторону: судя по представленной выборке, особо не злоупотребляют удалением по регулярке пока.

Comment: @jfs Комментарий был удален самим автором комментария (по тревоге!) Согласно временной шкале, это произошло после публикации следующего (оскорбительного) комментария, в ответ на упомянутый вами. Могу только догадываться, почему это произошло (например, человек решил, что «раз автору не надо, то стоит удалить»).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: понял, тогда я вообще примеров злоупотребления не вижу пока (по тревогам, которая регулярку дёргает).

Answer (score 10):

Я перебрал руками файл http://assets.rudevs.ru/no_longer_needed/07-10-2018_by_regexp.csv и попытался разобрать, какие из комментариев действительно стоило снести автоматически, а какие - стоило или оставить, или отдать на просмотр модераторам.

Какие комментарии стоило бы как минимум оставить на рассмотрение живыми модераторами:

- Все комментарии, оставленные из очередей проверки. Достаточно странно сносить их по желанию автора ответа.
- Автоматические комментарии, добавляемые при голосовании за закрытие вопроса.
- Негрубые нарушения code of conduct (например, "Читай книги по шарпу и не задавай глупых вопросов")
- Обоснования минусов
- Советы по оформлению
- Уточнения технических аспектов ответов или вопросов

Почему такие комментарии нельзя удалять автоматически?

- На многие из них стоило бы отреагировать модераторам (например, на нарушения Code of Conduct). Сейчас такие комментарии просто исчезают вникуда, и об это не уведомляется ни модератор, ни автор комментария (который продолжает такие комментарии плодить).
- Многие из них нельзя удалить без контекста. Например, как можно узнать, стал ли неактуальным комментарий

> Спасибо. Эту статью я читал, но, речь шла именно об отображении изображений через background.

или, например

> Любопытный способ. И EF транслируется в SQL-запрос нормально, можно я впишу в ваш ответ, а не в комментариях оставлю?

или

> Если Вам не сложно - прокомментируйте, пожалуйста, код. А конкретнее - последнюю строчку.

---

Я просмотрел те комментарии, по поводу которых у меня не возникало сомнений в правильности автоудаления. Практически все они попадали под одну из категорий:

- Спасибо
- Отметьте вопрос как принятый
- Тут принято задавать вопросы на русском

Эти категории достаточно полно покрываются выражением

```
спасибо|благодар|принятый|гугл|на русском|галоч|галка|как правильный
```

---

Результаты ревью:

- В файле **440** комментариев, попадающих под текущее выражение

  ```
  вопрос[ов|а|ы|ом|у|e]*|ответ[ов|а|ы|ом|у|e]*|спасибо|код[а]*|комментари[и|й]*
  ```
- Из них **69** я определил как ["не подлежащие автоудалению"](https://pastebin.com/dgntkPQV). То, что некоторые из них действительно стоило бы удалить, и не предпринять после этого никаких действий - это счастливое совпадение.

Те же комментарии я прогнал через упрощенное выражение `спасибо|благодар|принятый|гугл|на русском|галоч|галка|как правильный`

- **331** из не помеченных вручную как "требующие ревью" попали под новое выражение.
- Только **3 из 69** отмеченных как "требующие ревью" комментария попали под новое выражение (все три - из-за "спасибо" в теле).
- **40** из неотмеченных как "требующие ревью" было пропущено новым выражением.

Я взял [эти 40 комментариев](https://pastebin.com/kT4MLh61), пересмотрел еще раз, и понял, что большая часть из них на самом деле нуждалась в ревью. Т.е. я, как модератор, ожидал бы, что почти все из них пришли бы мне на ручную проверку, с анализом контекста. А не были бы снесены *бездушной регуляркой*.

Итого, по False Positive (ошибочно распознанные как подлежащие автоудалению):

- Текущая регулярка - 15% до 25%
- Предлагаемая новая - < 1%

Предлагаю заменить регулярку на новую, и посмотреть, станет ли больше тревог (застонут ли модераторы) и станет ли меньше ложных срабатываний.

Comment: Кто-нибудь мне скажет наконец? Что это за регулярка такая, в которой квадратные скобки вместо круглых и звезда вместо вопроса? или она таки просто косячная?

Comment: @vp_arth не знаю. может это не регулярка. может это свой язык. я вбивал как есть.

Comment: @vp_arth наверное, стоит это переписать как регулярку и сравнивать с ней. но как это сделать - не знаю. честно. т.к. не уверен насчет синтаксиса оригинала. даже если из анализа убрать оригинальную регулярку целиком - там числа не сильно поменяются. 440->475, но в них тоже есть false positive (11 из 35 точно)

Comment: Всё, что нужно сделать с регуляркой, чтобы она стала posix я описал в первом комментарии) И Qwertiy тоже писал, прямо перед баном) Может зря я это? =)

Comment: @vp_arth фильтр, судя по всему,  ждет не posix регулярку,  а свой собственный wild card синтаксис. У нас цель не регулярку сделать posix,  а фильтр настроить

Comment: @vp_arth, это к Николасу, потому что я [уже писал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7095/Автоматическое-удаление-комментариев-по-тревоге-более-не-является-необходимым#comment28311_7095), причём многократно, но никакой реакции не получил.

Comment: @PashaPash, а попробуй ограничение длинны добавить и проверить ещё раз. Например, для 32 символов будет выглядеть так: `^(?=.{1,32}$).*(спасибо|благодар|принятый|гугл|на русском|галоч|галка|как правильный)`

Comment: @Qwertiy пробовал,  ничего не дает. Т.е. отсеивает одно из трех ложных срабатываний, но промахивается по паре десятков настоящих спасиб. Особенно начинает мазать по "переведите вопрос на русский" и по "поставьте зеленую галку"

Comment: @PashaPash, последнее явно короче 32. Да и вообще, можно с длиной поиграться. Ты точно проверял на таком варианте как у меня, или в твоей версии вхождение должно было начинаться сначала?

Comment: Вы анализировали удаление "полезных" комментариев в связи с правками вопросов/ответов? Иногда бывает, спрашиваешь что-то у ТС, он благодарит за неравнодушие и отвечает коментом, а потом и в вопрос включает комент, и вот тут удаление своего комента-вопроса и "авто"-удаление его комментария бывает очень удобно.

Comment: Большое спасибо за анализ! Однозначно регулярное выражение можно улучшить! Буду рад помочь. П.С. «Многие из них нельзя удалить без контекста» — вероятно, можно, посмотрев временной лаг (комментарий опубликован довольно давно, к примеру, месяц+ назад. от текущего момента).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, но у нас же сейчас нет проверки на время написания?

Comment: Естественно, имелось в виду, что участник, который оставляет тревогу смотрит на текущую дату и дату публикацию комментария и понимает, что, вероятно, он комментарий не уже получит ответ или какое–либо иное ответное действие.

Answer (score 7):

Итак, что я вижу среди автоматически удаленных комментариев (кроме спасибов)?

Автокомментарии (про закрытие вопроса из из очередей проверок). Их удалять через тревогу нельзя! Потому что, у ставящего тревогу может сложиться ложное впечатление что таким образом комментарий "оспаривается" - хотя на самом деле происходит нечто прямо противоположное: теряется решение оспорить комментарий написав об этом его автору.

Более того, на некоторые из них я же тревогу и ставил. Рассчитывая что ее обработает модератор, а не регулярка...

Ну и просто очень много комментариев с мнениями и дополнениями, которые, возможно, и правда более не являются необходимыми - но не регулярке это решать:

> "261325","Вам дали хороший ответ. А вы хотите что бы все сделали за вас. Это не бесплатная фриланс-биржа."
>
> "479848","D-side - как мой вопрос может не отражать стремление разобраться? Если я его тут задал, то это уже значит что я приложил некие усилия, на то что бы разобраться в этом вопросе. Да и откуда Вам знать, может я уже читал документацию, но не смог понять информацию по поводу этого вопроса."
>
> "818052","стоит добавить, что второй тулбар входит в библиотеку поддержки AppCompat и ее необходимо подключить в проект, чтобы использовать"
>
> "834884","Это громкое заявление, на счёт многих не знающих. Уверен, очень малое количество программистов не нашли в себе сил прочитать учебник, а потом не понимают разницу между полями и переменными, а также не знают про области видимости."
>
> "845630","Мне надо чтобы он не выводил это а чтобы создавать точно такие-же строки только в приложении (код который вы мне дали он не подходит и не соответствует моему описанию)"
>
> "850932","Нет, я конечно понимаю, что форма вопроса несколько нагловата, но закрывать-то его зачем? Что непонятного в вопросе?"

Особенно хочу отметить последний, из вот [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/850932/178779), где был удален начальный комментарий в разговоре, и теперь комментарии там выглядят очень странно.

У меня два предложения:

1. удалить из регулярки все кроме вариаций "спасиба": их в выборке больше всего, и по ним же меньше всего ложноположительных результатов;
2. или же кроме регулярки поставить ограничение на максимальную длину удаляемого комментария: длинные комментарии обычно содержательны, кроме того на написание длинных комментариев требуется время - что естественным образом уменьшает их количество.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв! Да, можно добавить ограничение на длину комментария, на сколько я понимаю. Подскажите, что вы думаете по поводу необходимой максимальной длины? Единственное, стоит учесть, что шаблонные комментарии хорошо бы тоже как–то удалять (те, которые не удалились автоматически системой без тревог), а они длинные.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky вот их-то можно удалять только после того как исчезла причина (пост более не находится в очереди проверок), а при отсутствии такой возможности лучше оставлять. Иначе мы рискуем потерять фактор обучения новичков правильному поведению в очередях (на улучшение аудитов-то надежды нет)

Answer (score 4):

К вопросу [C++, избавление объекта от квалификатора const](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/862321/c-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-const/862326#862326)
 было добавлено несколько объемных комментариев, которые были удалены автоматически. Так были удалены 1 или 2 моих комменатрия, а также пара комментариев пользователя Максим (это я тестировал, что будет). Очевидно, что все эти комментарии не были ни оскорблением, ни «филлером», т.е. у них было определённое назначение, которое не пропало и на данный момент. Тем не менее, они пропали.

Нужно адаптировать автоудаление так, чтобы спорные комментарии скорее оставались, а не скорее удалялись. Эта проблема усугубляется ещё и тем, что восстановить эти комментарии не могут и модераторы. Поэтому если и иметь автоудаление, то оно должно работать только на комментарии, которые железно должны быть удалены.