# Удаленные комментарии по тревоге «более не является необходимым» с 10.07.2018 по 15.08.2018

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, комментарии, тревоги

Представляю вашему вниманию удаленные комментарии по тревоге «более не является необходимым» за период с 10.07.2018 по 15.08.2018. Комментарии разбиты на два файла (типа):

1. Комментарии, удаленные после ручной проверки модераторами: http://assets.rudevs.ru/no_longer_needed/15-08-2018_by_mods.csv
2. Комментарии, удаленные автоматикой: http://assets.rudevs.ru/no_longer_needed/15-08-2018_by_regexp.csv

Исходная инициатива раскрыта в вопросе [Автоматическое удаление комментариев по тревоге «более не является необходимым»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7095/6).

**Важно!**

Сегодня мы планируем поменять регулярное выражение с исходного:

> `вопрос[ов|а|ы|ом|у|e]*|ответ[ов|а|ы|ом|у|e]*|спасибо|код[а]*|комментари[и|й]*`

[На предложенное ответом к предыдущему отчету](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7675/6):

> `спасибо|благодар|принятый|гугл|на русском|галоч|галка|как правильный`

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что до сегодняшнего дня работала старая регулярка. Отчет по ней выше. Следующий отчет будет по комментариям, обработанным новым регулярным выражением!

Comment: А нельзя сначала прогнать тестово регулярку, а уже потом внедрять?

Comment: @Suvitruf Я сделал вывод, что PashaPash локально прогонял по имеющимся данным (удаленные регуляркой/вручную). То есть на имеющихся данных новая версия показывает лучшие цифры.

Comment: Все, обновили настройки!

Comment: Обе ссылки отдают 404

Comment: @vp_arth но ведь плюсуют же вопрос! Николай, "благодар" я бы изменил на явное "благодарю", т.к. может быть совсем невинная фраза, например: "благодаря этому ..."

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что это всё таки была обычная Posix-регулярка, которая делала немного не то, что от неё ожидали?

Comment: @vp_arth что-то она точно делала :D

Comment: Правил ссылки! Спасибо! Регулярка работала как должна была :)

Comment: `[ов|а|ы|ом|у|e]*` - значит 0 или более символов `авемоуы|`. То, что оно работало почти корректно - совпадение. Если я не прав, хотелось бы таки узнать(я спрашивал об этом уже около десятка раз), что за стандарт регулярных выражений тут использован.

Comment: "как правильный"- можно еще добавить "как принятый", ибо как правило у задачи может быть несколько решений, и все они являются правильными

Comment: @Anamnian Слова в регулярном выражении подобраны на основе текущих данных, то есть статистики (см. ссылку на ответ PashaPash).

Comment: @vp_arth Выяснил, что в движке [используется регулярные выражения от MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) c настройками `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture`.