# Удаленные комментарии по тревоге «более не является необходимым» с 15.08.2018 по 25.09.2018

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, комментарии, тревоги

Представляю вашему вниманию удаленные комментарии по тревоге «более не является необходимым» за период с 15.08.2018 по 25.09.2018.  Как обычно, комментарии разбиты на два файла (типа):

1. Комментарии, удаленные после ручной проверки модераторами: http://assets.rudevs.ru/no_longer_needed/25_09_2018_by_mods.csv
2. Комментарии, удаленные автоматикой: http://assets.rudevs.ru/no_longer_needed/25_09_2018_by_regexp.csv

Дополнительные ссылки:

- Исходная инициатива раскрыта в вопросе [Автоматическое удаление комментариев по тревоге «более не является необходимым»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7095).
- Месяц назад, во время предыдущей проверки, мы изменили регулярное выражение. Подробности в вопросе [Удаленные комментарии по тревоге «более не является необходимым» с 10.07.2018 по 15.08.2018](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7681).

Будем рады видеть ваши отзывы!

Comment: А комментарии, которые были удалены, все продолжают висеть где-то и их видно тем у кого репа больше 20.000?

Comment: @Bharata нет, не видно.

Comment: Nicolas, а предыдущие удалялись ? наткнулся на сентябрь [Спасибо за ответы)!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/879270/#comment1428876_879270). Вероятно стоит дополнить регулярку проверки конкретными фразами, во избежание удаления нужно.

Answer (score 4):

Присоединяюсь к предложениям составить регулярку, которая будет удалять только комментарии, которые не содержат никаких других слов кроме «бесполезных».

Предлагаю такое выражение:

```
^([^а-яА-Я]|спасибо|большое|вам|ок|понял|да|всем|ясно|точно|огромное|за|ответ|помогло|помощь|тебе|работает|друг|и)+$
```

Это выражение отлавливает 1761 комментарий из 1912 (92%). При этом можно с большой уверенностью утверждать, что комментарий, который состоит только из перечисленных слов, не содержит важной информации, что защищает от ложных срабатываний.

Демонстрация выражения на DBFiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nWgR92433XWmg4ecf3erBw/0

Выражение нужно протестировать на более крупной выборке комментариев. Возможно будет даже лучше использовать более короткие варианты. Например, выражения:

```
^([^а-яА-Я]|спасибо|большое|вам|ок|понял|да|всем)+$
^([^а-яА-Я]|спасибо|большое|вам)+$
```

отлавливают 90% и 86% приведенных комментариев, соответственно

Answer (score 3):

Сложно по таким данным что-то сказать, т.к. контекста нет. Не ясно, в каком виде был комментарий.

К примеру:

1. ["2273","Спасибо! Мне нужно поставить коммиты последовательно, неважно в каком порядке, главное хоть как-то заставить работать git rebase. Я предположил, что я делаю что-то не в том порядке, потому что варианты того, что написать вместо ""???"" я иногда брал из примеров и всё равно не работало."](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2272/15479). Вполне себе нормальный коммент. Возможно, в регулярку стоит добавить проверку на длину. И если комментарий (к примеру, "спасибо") больше этой длины, то не удалять.
2. ["274920","Спасибо только как это может помочь заменить скажем только первое вхождение?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/274920/15479). Вполне себе нормальный уточняющий комментарий. Опять же, длину комментария проверять.
3. ["571306","Спасибо за ответ, но он теперь не принимает даже обычные символы типа `Sergey`"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571306/15479). Уточняющий комментарий.
4. ["585992","Код - написаная среда окружения. Задача (в более широком смысле) обновлять вьюшку которая выводится на экран, в зависимости от того, что придёт на камеру. А в приложении картинка выглядит примерно [так](http://static3.depositphotos.com/1000864/183/i/950/depositphotos_1838647-stock-photo-noise-4.jpg). Всё это нужно делать со скоростью 24-30 кадров в секунду."](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/585992/15479)
   . Комментарий, описывающий задачу. Лучше, конечно же, было в вопрос эту инфу добавить.
5. ["621784","Да, точно. В запросе sub_menu немного ошибся, но мой код как и ваш работает. Но все равно спасибо.
   А как сделать теперь то, что после моего предложения? ""Если есть подменю у меню, то оставлять тег span перед ul и создавать список(2 строчки, к которым это относится)"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/621784/15479)
6. ["868843","@Kromster, спасибо, оказывается там можно найти старую версию DUnit, которая вполне работает начиная аж с Delphi5. Вопрос решен."](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/868843/15479)
7. ["878492","Спасибо за помощь. Но с моим текущим уровнем знаний я не совсем понимаю, как вызов родительского метода repaint() помогает исправить баг в программе. Если не сложно, объясни поподробнее или укажи, где можно об этом прочитать)"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/878492/15479)
   .

Довольно полезные "спасибо" комментарии удалены. Если проверять длину сообщения (скажем, если оно больше 20-25 символов), то как "спасибо" не удалять. Большую часть обычных "спасибо" оно продолжит удалять, но потенциально важные "спасибо" перестанет.

Comment: Вне контекста, нельзя сказать, нужно ли было их оставить или нет. Уточняющие комментарии зачастую устаревают и более не являются необходимыми, если автор вопроса/ответа на них отреагировал и включил уточнение в вопрос/ответ.

Comment: @Kromster поэтому я и предлагаю такие комментарии не удалять автоматикой)

Comment: Можете предложить новый regex?

Comment: @PashaPash я не знаю, какие ограничение на регулярку налагаются. Из того, что я видел раньше, там просто строка с кучей "или", по сути. Какие туда проверки можно добавить?

Comment: там вроде бы обычное регулярное выражение. скорее всего под .net. Уточню у КМ.

Comment: Вот такую регулярку можно использовать для ограничений на длину: `^(?=.{0,20}).*(спасибо|благодар|принятый|гугл|на русском|галоч|галка|как правильный).*$`. Но выглядит каким-то извращением, лучше уговорить программистов сделать две проверки вместо одной.